# Summarize data on 2 axis table - excel

Tags: excel, summary

Ive got a spreadsheet of with about 1000 rows, for each row there are the following columns "cost", "sub set", "room". There are 10 subset types, and 15 room types.

I want to summarize the cost data on in a table with the X axis being "sub set", and on the Y axis being "room". So that at a glance anyone can see the cost of "sub set A" in "room B" is $xvalue.

My default was to build this using `SUMIF` but im not sure this is best suited for a 2 axis summary, what would you suggest the best way of doing this is ?

Answer (score 0):

I started exploring a further into this after i wrote the post and came across the `SUMIFS` function, which seems to do the trick. Would be interested to see if there is a more eloquent way to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pivot Tables. You have wide options to Select from.

```
Insert--> Pivot table
```

All your columns will be listed in fields

1) In the Values give sum of values.

2) In rows give sub set and Room

Pivot is  very powerful. Explore for more options